# How to rotate a bitmap in android in 2 Directions

Tags: android, matrix, bitmap, image-rotation

I know how to rotate a bitmap clockwise or counter-clockwise. Now I want to rotate a bitmap clockwise and diagonally at the same time i.e. in two directions at the same time. How can I do this?

Comment: what do you mean by rotating bi-directionally?

Comment: I know I am not able to clearly ask. Let me try again.
We can rotate an image clock wise and anti clockwise right.
What I want to do is I want it to rotate it like the belt is moving on running machine. When I look at the belt it is revolving backward and I am running forward. Likewise I want to rotate an image.Did I clear what I wanted to ask?